# Apache не загружает страницу вместо выполнения кода

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache

Есть некий скрипт который формирует табличку на основе определенных полей в БД

```
$cur_user_id = get_current_user_id();
$user_info = get_userdata($cur_user_id);


$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `tariffofsite` WHERE  `A` = 
'".$user_info->Adress ."' LIMIT 0 , 30");
$tablehead = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tariffofsite` WHERE `A` = 'Дом'");
while ($head = mysql_fetch_row($tablehead)) {//разбираем заголовки столбцов


while ($adress = mysql_fetch_row($res)){    //разбираем данные
        echo '<div class="table-responsive">          
            <table class="table">
            <tr>';
            for ($i=0; $i < 17; $i++) {     //циклом выводим заголовоки 
столбцов    
        echo "<td>".$head[$i]."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>
    <tr>";

    for ($i=0; $i < 17; $i++) { //циклом выводим данные столбцов

        echo "<td>".$adress[$i]. "</td>";
    }
        echo '</tr>
                </table>';
    }
}
```

Если я выполняю данный скрипт на голой страничке на сервере, он без проблем отдает мне таблицу и я доволен, а если этот же скрипт я пытаюсь запустить из-под Вордпресса то получаю (см. скрин)

[image: Получаемый результат]

Причем винда (под которой крутится апач) в первый раз отдала ошибку и отправляла данные на серевера майков, потом она укорно молчала, в логах апач-сервера - чисто.
Как мне заставить работать скрипт, а не ронять апач (ну а апач после результата скрина продолжает в обычном режиме крутить Вордпресс и открывать другие странички)

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, прекратите использовать расширение `mysql`. Оно давно устарело и не поддерживается в PHP 7, с которым Вы наверняка рано или поздно столкнётесь.

Во-вторых, в WordPress есть собственный API для работы с базами данных. Читайте про глобальную переменную `$wpdb` и всё, что с ней связано (например, [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wpdb)).

В-третьих, в Вашем случае скорее всего подойдёт метод `get_results`. Например, как-то так:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results(""SELECT * FROM  '".$tableName"' WHERE  `A` = '".$user_info->Adress ."' LIMIT 0 , 30"");
```